# Moveit Custom Controller

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit, ros-melodic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use Moveit and Gazebo with a custom controller [provided by my robot's manufacturer](https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/sawyer_simulator/blob/master/sawyer_sim_controllers/include/sawyer_sim_controllers/electric_gripper_controller.h). When I launch both moveit(+ rviz) and gazebo and try to plan, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1586291253.875844268, 5322.770000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ right_gripper_l_finger_joint right_j0 right_j1 right_j2 right_j3 right_j4 right_j5 right_j6 ]
[ERROR] [1586291253.875874497, 5322.770000000]: Known controllers and their joints:
controller '/robot/limb/right' controls joints:
  right_j0
  right_j1
  right_j2
  right_j3
  right_j4
  right_j5
  right_j6
```

Note, that this works when I disable the gripper, meaning that moveit doesn't know what to do with the `right_gripper_l_finger_joint`. However, I specify the contoller for this joint in my controller manager yaml file like so:

```
controller_list:
# ... 
  - name: /io/end_effector
    action_ns: right_gripper
    type: sawyer_sim_controllers/ElectricGripperController
    default: true
    joints:
      - right_gripper_l_finger_joint
```

I've verified that the name and action namespace listed are correct:

```
>>># rostopic list | grep right_gripper
    /io/end_effector/right_gripper/command
    /io/end_effector/right_gripper/config
    /io/end_effector/right_gripper/state
```

And if I inspect the running controllers with `rosservice call /robot/controller_manager/list_controllers` I see my controller running:

```
controller: 
  - name: "electric_gripper_controller"
    state: "running"
    type: "sawyer_sim_controllers/ElectricGripperController"
    claimed_resources: 
      -  hardware_interface: "sawyer_hardware_interface::SharedJointInterface"
         resources: [right_gripper_l_finger_joint/MAIN_SETPOINT_COMMAND, right_gripper_r_finger_joint/MAIN_SETPOINT_COMMAND]
```

So, is there a piece here that I'm missing?

Edit:

Somehow I missed this before, but when starting RViz and moveit, it logs the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1586294845.676943431, 116.035000000]: Unknown controller type: sawyer_sim_controllers/ElectricGripperController
```

Still not sure what causes this as my ros params seem to be set up correctly and the controller manager knows about this type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348730/moveit-custom-controller/) by [rklutz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49792/rklutz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-08**:
You're last edit seems to point to a cause here. (I'm assuming) MoveIt doesn't appear to know that type of controller. That would cause it to fail loading that stanza, leading to no controllers for your `right_gripper_l_finger_joint`, leading to the error message you quoted earlier.

**Comment by [rklutz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49792/rklutz/) on 2020-04-08**:
Right, I understand that moveit doesn't know about the controller, but given that it is a [subclass of EffortJointInterface](https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/sawyer_simulator/blob/master/sawyer_hardware_interface/include/sawyer_hardware_interface/shared_joint_interface.h), it should still be able to work with it, right? Or is it a matter of somehow notifying moveit about it's existence?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-08**:
There's a difference between a MoveIt controller and a `ros_control` controller. You link to a package providing `ros_control` plugins/controllers/capabilities.

MoveIt doesn't do anything directly with `ros_control` controllers.

That may be the main issue here. If `sawyer_sim_controllers/ElectricGripperController` is actually a `ros_control` controller, you cannot just use it with MoveIt directly.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2020-04-16**:
I'm not sure if MoveIt or ros_control is giving you that "Unknown controller type", here's a trick for improving the verbosity of your terminal. Add to .bash.rc

```
export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='${logger}: ${message}'
```

More info: http://dav.ee/blog/notes/archives/898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're mixing up two types of controller yaml files: MoveIt and ros_control (confusing I know)

Examples:

- A ros_control configuration yaml looks like this: [rrbot_controllers.yaml](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate/blob/melodic-devel/rrbot_control/config/rrbot_controllers.yaml)
- A MoveIt configuration yaml looks like this: [panda_gripper_controllers.yaml](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/blob/melodic-devel/config/panda_gripper_controllers.yaml)

They both have a `type` field, and you just have yours mixed up. For the `ElectricGripperController` the type should be "GripperCommand". Your other configs in that yaml are wrong also.

Your MoveIt configuration by default uses the MoveItSimpleControllerManager. Its simple, [so it only supports two types](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_plugins/moveit_simple_controller_manager/src/moveit_simple_controller_manager.cpp): "FollowJointTrajectory" and "GripperCommand"

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rklutz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49792/rklutz/) on 2020-04-20**:
Hey, thanks for looking into this. Since initially asking the question, I modified the parameters specified in my yaml files, but now I'm seeing the problem might be that there is no actionlib server running to handle the gripper commands. I see that moveit expects to find one at the topics found under the `action_ns`. In my case rethink provides a `joint_trajectory_action_server.py` script that provides this, but I can't find an equivalent to handle the gripper. The gazebo plugins for my robot do publish/subscribe to `/io/end_effector/right_gripper/command`, `.../right_gripper/state`. and `.../right_gripper/config`. The [scripts they provide](https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/intera_sdk/blob/master/intera_examples/scripts/gripper_keyboard.py) can use this interface, but I'm guessing Moveit cannot. Sounds like I'll have to write this myself?

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2020-04-22**:
I'm not sure the specifics of the Sawyer Gazebo implementation. If they didn't include a gripper action server, that was certainly an oversight. Just give Rethink support a call ;-)

**Comment by [rklutz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49792/rklutz/) on 2020-04-22**:
Haha, I've been on hold for an hour, almost like they went out of business or something...

Anyways, I went ahead and implemented the interface myself. Things seem to be working now.  Thanks!